# How to disable VS Code from auto-installing certain extensions when enable Settings Sync on a newly install VS Code?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Settings Sync helps to track the extensions installed on one machine, and automatically install them on a newly installed VS Code.

My issue is that I sometimes just install some extensions for evaluation and don't want to track my installation on them. Or sometimes an extension is depreciated and I would like to remove it from Settings Sync's tracking. Currently for both case, Settings Sync would track those extensions with no difference. This leads to the need to remove a great number of extension after I enabling sync on a new VS Code.

Is there a way to stop Setting Sync from tracking some of the extensions?